# Subquery not allowed

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to "auto-insert" my `MONEY` field on this table as the quantity of a product times the price of the product. I have the quantity value but the price will come from the foreign key `PRODUCT_ID` but I get error message:

> Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions
>   are allowed.

This is the table. How can I do this "auto-insert"? If it is not possible this way please tell me another way I can do that. Thanks in advance.

```
CREATE TABLE ORDER_DETAILS
(
NUM_ORDER INT PRIMARY KEY,
PRODUCT_ID VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
QUANTIITY INT NOT NULL,
MONEY AS (QUANTITY * (SELECT PRICE FROM PRODUCTS WHERE PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_ID = PRODUCT_ID)),
ORDER_DATE DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE()
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create a user defined function for this.

```
CREATE TABLE ORDER_DETAILS
(
NUM_ORDER INT PRIMARY KEY,
PRODUCT_ID VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
QUANTIITY INT NOT NULL,
MONEY AS dbo.YourFunction(Quntity,ProductId),
ORDER_DATE DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't write this line:

```
MONEY AS (QUANTITY * (SELECT PRICE FROM PRODUCTS WHERE PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_ID = PRODUCT_ID))
```

To count automatically value of this attribute you have to use one of these:

1. Trigger
2. User defined function